# Docs/Utility to View WPF Control Template?

Tags: .net, wpf, controltemplate

Is there documentation/utility that shows the default control template of a given control? I'd like to see how a given control is constructed so I can customize the behavior correctly and/or choose to use a style instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a [number](http://www.jimandkatrin.com/codeblog/2008/06/wpf-getting-default-control-templates.html) [of](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/02/14/wpfdefaulttemplate) [links](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=a3e4319b-b790-40b6-b92a-4b9b0b9d65b9) that demonstrate doing this.

I would also check out [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), which comes with some code snippets called *Simple Styles.* These are templates for all of the controls that are not quite as complex as the default behavior, which can be a bit esoteric at times.

Comment: Kaxaml is awesome for prototyping, but it won't show you the default template for a control.

Comment: None of these links (of the two that are still working) will show you the default control template unless you write some code first. So far StyleSnooper and ShowMeTheTemplate are the only tools I've found that don't require writing code to see the templates. However, SMTT seems to be missing a bunch of controls. Anyone know if Visual Studio 2010 makes this easier? Or Expression Blend?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you want to try [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/).  It can load an assembly and show you the effective XAML that defines each control's `ControlTemplate`.

http://dotnet-gui.com/blogs/wpf_tools_blog/WindowsLiveWriter/StyleSnooperDenStandardStylesaufderSpur_F211/image_2.png

Both binary and source versions are available.  This tool is a really great one to have in your WPF arsenal.